# R shiny - Animated random numbers to ValueBox

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make a little animation in R shiny.

The core is to put a `sample(1:100, 1)`, in a `valueBox`, but I'd like to make an animation by printing random numbers for some seconds and and in the end print the `sample` result.

I've found the following code, which uses JavaScript. The problem is that the code generates an animation from 0 to the random number generated in `sample`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

js <- "
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('anim',
 function(x){

    var $box = $('#' + x.id + ' div.small-box');
    var value = x.value;

    var $icon = $box.find('i.fa');

    var $s = $box.find('div.inner h3');
    var o = {value: 0};
    $.Animation( o, {
        value: value
      }, {
        duration: 1000
      }).progress(function(e) {
          $s.text((e.tweens[0].now).toFixed(0));
    });

  }
);"

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
    fluidRow(
      tagAppendAttributes(
        valueBox("", subtitle = "Número sorteado",
                 icon = icon("server"),
                 color = "blue"
        ),
        id = "mybox"
      )
    ),
    br(),
    actionButton("btn", "Change value")
  )
)

# Server response
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input[["btn"]], {
    rv(sample(1:100, 1))
  })

  observeEvent(rv(), {
    for(i in 1:30){
      session$sendCustomMessage("anim", list(id = "mybox", value = rv()))
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've also found [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/m3sxpLrj/) that makes exactly what I want in JS, but I couldn't put it in shiny.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to resort to Javascript.  Shiny has a [built-in timer](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/timer.html).

This MWE creates a value box displaying an integer chosen at random in the range 1 to 100 that updates once a second.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    valueBoxOutput("random")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$random <- renderValueBox({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    valueBox("Value", sample(1:100, 1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How could we stop in some number after a while?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. Stop after, say, 50 updates or after two minutes? Or when a given number is sampled?